# redundancia con los return en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

He conseguido recorrer un json en mi aplicación. Es el siguiente:

```
 {"cover": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "titulo": "Entrada destacada",
            "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "categoria": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Restaurantes"
            },
            "subcategory": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Hamburguesería"
            },
        }
    ],
}
```

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera...

```
    import React from "react";
    import data from "../data/data.json";

const Cover = () => {
  return Object.values(data.cover).map((item) => {
    return (
      <section key={item.id}>
        <article>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>{item.titulo}</h1>
              <h2>{item.descripcion}</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <p>{item.categoria.name}</p>
                <p>{item.subcategoria.name}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>
    );
  });
};

export default Cover;
```

Todo funciona bien. Pero la duda que tengo al respecto es: ¿no se supone que al tratarse Cover de un componente declarado como una arrow function, las llaves ya llevarían implícito el return? ¿Por qué me obliga a ponerlo dos veces? ¿Esto no se verá como una mala práctica en un proyecto serio?
He tratado de quitarlos y probar varias combinaciones pero me da errores que no dejan que pinte absolutamente nada...

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `return` es requerido si le especificas el cuerpo a la función de lo contrario no.

Ejemplo:

```js
var fnConCuerpo = ()=> { return 'Tengo el cuerpo definido'};
var fnSinConCuerpo = ()=> 'No tengo el cuerpo definido';

console.log(fnConCuerpo());
console.log(fnSinConCuerpo());
```

La diferencia entre ambos es que en funciones con cuerpo puedes escribir controles de flujos y ejecutar mas de 1 funcion.

---

De si es buena practica o no depende de los estadares de tu equipo. Ambas son validas en el estandar javascript asi que a mi parecer no hay diferencia si buena o mala practica.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres ahorrarte el `return` puedes usar escribir tu codigo asi

```
import React from "react";
import data from "../data/data.json";

const Cover = () =>
  Object.values(data.cover).map((item) => (
    <section key={item.id}>
      <article>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>{item.titulo}</h1>
            <h2>{item.descripcion}</h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <p>{item.categoria.name}</p>
              <p>{item.subcategoria.name}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  ));

export default Cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Arrow functions y JSX ReactJS

> ¿no se supone que al tratarse Cover de un componente declarado como una arrow function, las llaves ya llevarían implícito el return?

En la [documentación MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) se puede leer:

> los {brackets} (Parentesis) y el "return" son opcionales, pero pueden ser requeridos.

Los brackets son requeridos por ejemplo, cuando se necesita mas de una línea de código **multiple statements** para procesar la función y, como la función no sabe "que" o "cuando" va a regresar, se debe especificar el `return` explícitamente.

---

> ¿Por qué me obliga a ponerlo dos veces? ¿Esto no se verá como una mala práctica en un proyecto serio?

Ahora, en el contexto `React/JSX`, se puede devolver un `stateless component` como en este caso `Cover`, usando la técnica `inline return`,  (donde el `return` va implícito).

En este caso solo se tiene un **single statementent** `Object.values->map` y dentro solo se está regresando `JSX`, entonces se puede prescindir del uso de paréntesis en ambas `arrow function`.

Demo:

```js
const data = {
      property:null,
      cover:[
        {
            id: 'Q',
            titulo: 'Título 1',
            descripcion: 'descripcion 1'
        },
        {
            id: 'R',
            titulo: 'Título 2',
            descripcion: 'descripcion 2'
        },
        {
            id: 'S',
            titulo: 'Título 3',
            descripcion: 'descripcion 3'
        },
        {
            id: 'T',
            titulo: 'Título 4',
            descripcion: 'descripcion 4'
        }
    ]
 } 
function App(){
  return <Cover />
}

//stateless component
//inline return, 
//single statement Object.values 
//arrow fn: sin parentesis, ni return
const Cover = () => Object.values(data.cover).map((item) =>
      <section key={item.id}>
        <article>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>{item.titulo}</h1>
              <h1>{item.descripcion}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>);
 
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.